# Master page property access from Content page

Tags: .net, asp.net, master-pages

FROM BOOK:

> To reference public properties in a master page, we add the @MasterType declaration to the content page and reference the property using Master.<PropertyName>.

**QUESTION**: But what happens internally? Does all of the master's and content page's properties, function gets complied into one class? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page class has a reference (property) to the master page class. When a page is requested asp.net instantiate a object from your page class and set the master page property to a instance of the master page.